# How to get a list of my Facebook friends?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to build a management app in C# (probably ASP.NET C# using .NET 4). I would like to GET a list of my Facebook friends and then save there names, display pic, Date of friendship and there Facebook UserID AND/OR Username.

When you run the application for the first time, it should retrieve the details and then log a date time stamp against the record. Then when you run the application again it will make a check, if they exist in the database but NOT in Facebook then create a new record in another table called,deleted`. I will then query that table separately to display the deleted people. Ideally i need this application to run daily to get an idea of WHEN they deleted me.

I am pretty sure Facebook offers an API that i can use to GET my friends-list? Any examples on sample code for getting your own friends-list?

Comment: Start by reading about [facebook's own well documented APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/).

Comment: Maybe you could assist and show me which API call it is?

Comment: The easiest way to retrieve your own friends list is by using Windows PowerShell and http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com. Call New-FBConnection and then Get-FBFriend. For something this simple you don't need to learn the Facebook API, although it helps to understand the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve the names and ids for the users in your friend list by performing a GET request to `/me/friends` endpoint of the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/). In order to make this request, a user access token with user_friends permission is required. You can read more about access tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

Once you have a valid Access Token, you can simply make a GET request using any of the Facebook SDK or simply by using the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token={Access_Token}
```

This will return the list of name and user id for the users in your friend list.

You can always use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1786565687?fields=id,name) to test your request and FQL queries.

Comment: can you also help with this question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825015/display-fql-results-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: I've never worked on ASP platform before. But I this it can be easily done by using Grid View and mapping the Arraylist of object with it. You can find some tutorial on it on MSDN website. Sorry about that.