# Display FQL results in DataGridView using C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have my FQL query and i have my access token. But how do i display FQL results in GRID VIEW using C# and ASP.NET?

**FQL:**

```
SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name, friend_count, pic_big  
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

**This is what i have tried:**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Facebook;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var fb = new FacebookClient("{My Access Token}");

                dynamic result = fb.Get("/me");
                var name = result.name;

               MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have realized that the data is returned from Facebook as JSON so i attempt to `deserialize` but still now luck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Facebook;
using System.Dynamic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        public class MyFriends
        {
            public int uid {get; set;}
            public string username {get; set;}
            public string first_name {get; set;}
            public string last_name {get; set;}
            public int friend_count {get; set;}
            public string pic_big {get; set;}
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient("2A64ZAIeJVIbdZAxXRZCwYf5Bg27OgZDZD");

            var query = string.Format("SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name, friend_count, pic_big  FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.q = query;
            dynamic results = fb.Get("/fql", parameters);

            results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyFriends>(results);

            //MessageBox.Show("Hi " + results);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your title you mention DataGridView, but in your code you dont assign the result from the query to any datagridview. Are you missing some code from this sample?

Comment: The problem is that i cannot deserialize the JSON and therefore its pointless to add the DataGridView.

Comment: I havent worked with the facebook api, but isent "results" a (json) array? Looks like you deserialize it as a single object, did you try to alter it to IEnumerabe<MyFriends>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# `Winforms` solution using a `DataGridView` control like you specify in the title.

---

1) **Modify your `MyFriend` class**, I changed it a little bit

```
public class MyFriends
{
    public long uid { get; set; }            
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public long? friend_count { get; set; }  //nullable
    public string pic_big { get; set; }
}
```

2) Add DataGridView control to your form

3) **Deserialize** your `result.data` using `JsonConvert` to a List. You should also pass `result.data.ToString()` or it will give an exception.

4) **Bind** your new list to `DataGridView.Datasource`

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("accessToken");

var query = string.Format(@"SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name, friend_count, pic_big 
                            FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.q = query;
dynamic results = fb.Get("/fql", parameters);

List<MyFriends> q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyFriends>>(results.data.ToString());

dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Ill be interested in the code-behind in your "Login to Facebook" button :) ?

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Of course, I found that in a very interesting [blog post](http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-writing-your-first-facebook-application-v6). Great for a quick start

Comment: @PriceCheaperton it was updated to v6 and there's a downloadable solution that works perfectly :)

Comment: @Kiquenet I posted the link just above, there's a login form sample