# facebook login via vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, facebook

I am planning to create a vb.net application that will be synchronized with user's facebook account. I want to create an application that allows the user to login their accounts, fetch notifications, friend requests, view/reply/create messages and other activities they want to fetch from facebook via this vb.net application.

My problem is I don't have any idea where to start. I mean, do I need to learn how to create crawler or something? What API's, SDK's do I have to study for this? Where is the best place to start? Are there any websites or articles that are discussing these kind of things also?

Thank you for insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert but I've done a [small project in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825015/display-fql-results-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp-winforms/20895023#20895023)

You should start installing the [Facebook SDK](http://www.nuget.org/packages/facebook) from NuGet and reading some documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/ The registration on **Facebook Developers** is mandatory to receive to get your **App Key**

**Getting an App Key**:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Register
3. Create New App. Choose some unique `App Name` 
   [image]
4. Once you've created your app, you get your `App ID` key.

   [image]

**Back to Visual Studio - Creating your .Net Project**

I strongly suggest you download this working project [FB-CSharp-SDK-First-FB-Application](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/FB-CSharp-SDK-First-FB-Application)
and read how it works on thig [blog post](http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-writing-your-first-facebook-application-v6). It is C# but you should be able to easily reproduce it in VB.Net.

Don't forget to edit `AppId` string and write your own key!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const string AppId = "APP KEY";
    private const string ExtendedPermissions = "user_about_me,read_stream";
    private string _accessToken;

    [...]

 }
```

Once you added your `App Key` you can run the program. Upon clicking "**Login**" it'll open a small webBrowser control that let you login into facebook. The correct login procedure returns a `facebookOAuthResult` Object that contains your `AccessToken`.

You must pass your `AccessToken` when you instantiate `FacebookClient`, the class that you will use for your requests. In this case you're simply getting your identity information and get your `name` from the result of the webrequest (that is in `JSON` format).

```
    private void DisplayAppropriateMessage(FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult)
    {
        if (facebookOAuthResult != null)
        {
            if (facebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                _accessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
                var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken);

                dynamic result = fb.Get("/me");
                var name = result.name;

                // for .net 3.5
                //var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("/me");
                //var name = (string)result["name"];

                MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);
                btnLogout.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(facebookOAuthResult.ErrorDescription);
            }
        }
    }
```

To test your queries on the fly, you can use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me).

**I guess it's enough to start! Good Luck**

Comment: Thank you for this starting point details. I will give time to study theses things. Thank you so much for the insights...