# how to get source code from link with user name and password in vb or c#

Tags: vb.net

i try to get code source from my facebook account bet i get only the login page code source...

i assumes its happens because problem with cookie

my code...

```
'download data from url and return string of the source code
Public Shared Function getSourceCode(address As String) As String
    Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing

    'Address of URL
    Dim URL As String = address
    ' Get HTML data
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()

    Try
        client.Proxy = Nothing
        Dim data As Stream = client.OpenRead(URL)
        reader = New StreamReader(data)
    Catch
        'error
    End Try

    If reader IsNot Nothing Then Return reader.ReadToEnd

    Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see how you try to get *source code*. You mean something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [facebook login via vb.net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900715/facebook-login-via-vb-net-application)

Comment: thanks about the comments... my function get url and returns the source code from the url page... becuse the link is to my facebook account its return me the source code of login page..... my question is how to get into my facebook account programmatically with user name and password and get the home page code source... my problet is that i stack on login page

Comment: It's not that simple. You need a library and an api key to do that. See the link i posted